# Restore multiple files with rdiff-backup

Tags: windows, backup-restoration, rdiff-backup

Has anyone written a script to restore multiple files/directories at once using [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) on windows?  Single files work fine.

Comment: rdiff != rdiff-backup; you might get more answers if you title your question appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking here. Rdiff backup should be as simple as

```
rdiff-backup /sourcedir /backupdir.
```

To restore all backed up files

```
rdiff-backup -r now /backupdir /restoredirectory
```

Maybe if you elaborate a bit on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: you know, I got this to work, (its on windows)--

The error messages I was getting tricked me into thinking the windows version couldn't do this yet